# PHP PDO can't bind values

Tags: php, pdo, bind, sql-injection, sanitization

I am trying to do a small search engine for a website.

This is the simple code

```
if ( Input::issetGet('q') ) {

        $q = Input::get('q');

        if ( !empty($q) ) {

            $keywords = explode(' ', $q);

            $findPhones = $dbh->prepare("
                SELECT 
                    p.id AS pId, p.name AS pName, p.original_price, p.price, p.img, p.brand, p.model, p.color, p.o_s, p.status, p.description,
                    b.id, b.name AS bName, 
                    m.id, m.name AS mName
                FROM phones AS p
                LEFT JOIN brands AS b ON p.brand = b.id
                LEFT JOIN phone_models AS m ON p.model = m.id
                WHERE p.name LIKE '%" . implode("%' OR p.name LIKE '%", $keywords) . "%'  
                OR p.description LIKE '%" . implode("%' OR p.description LIKE '%", $keywords) . "%' 
                OR b.name LIKE '%" . implode("%' OR b.name LIKE '%", $keywords) . "%'  
                ORDER BY p.id DESC
            ");
            $findPhones->execute();
            $phones = $findPhones->fetchAll();

        }
    }
```

Let me quickly explain. If I search for `samsung`, this query will check if the `p.name`, `p.description` or `b.name` contain this word. If I search for `samsung computers` the query will check if `p.name`, `p.description` or `b.name` contain either the word `samsung` or `computers` and so on for more search terms.

The problem is that I can't find a way to bind `$keywords`, I would like not to hardcode it like in the query, but to pass it when I execute the query.

I tried with `?` and `:keyword`, but none worked. If I dump the query, the `LIKE` statements are empty, `""`.

My guess is that the problem lays in the implode function which is inside the query, it won't allow me to parameterize the array `$keywords`.

At this point I simply query the database without binding values and I am open for SQL Injection.

Q: How can I bind the array `keywords`, and if not possible, what's the best way to protect from SQL Injection in this case ?

Thank you

Comment: Check that question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/920353/php-pdo-can-i-bind-an-array-to-an-in-condition

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15990857/reference-frequently-asked-questions-about-pdo

Comment: Thank you for replying, but both those questions hard code the variables into the query, I want to bind them

Comment: Not in my example, check the accepted answer.

Comment: @YourCommonSense wins for being the most helpful person on StackOverflow, and I totally mean that sarcastically.

Comment: OP, try using the "in" statement instead of a bunch of ORs. That'll allow you to pass in a comma delineated set to compare against, unless I'm misunderstanding your question in some way.